# File uoload error in Codeigniter 3

Tags: file-upload, codeigniter-3

I am trying to upload file in a folder in root directory but get the following error.

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500
```

I am using codeigniter version 3.1.2.

In previous versions of CI, I was able to upload the file with similar code. Is there any changes to the file upload process or am I missing some configuration?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter upload fail no error logs no error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717111/codeigniter-upload-fail-no-error-logs-no-error-reporting)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have php_fileinfo.dll extension installed ? you need to access php.ini and uncommented the line that has php_fileinfo.php or otherwise you can use [this](https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php) library