# Uploading Image File in Codeigniter 3 returns error 500

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So I'm trying to insert in the database and upload a file. But when I'm trying to submit, it returns a server error.

The same code is working on my other project but it is using CI2, i checked the .htaccess and its all the same

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

I think the problem is in the `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')` because i tried to comment out from this part and display echo the config array and there's no error but when i tried to uncomment up to this part, the error shows.

Controller

```
public function add_now(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Event_Name', 'Event Name', 'trim|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Event_Start', 'Start Date', 'trim|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Event_End', 'End Date', 'trim|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Event_Location', 'Location', 'trim|strip_tags');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->add();
    }
    else{   
        $query = $this->events_model->do_upload();
        if($query){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Successful!');
            $this->index();
        }
        else{
            if(!$this->session->flashdata('upload_error')){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('failed', 'Failed!');
            }
            $this->add();
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
public function do_upload(){
    
    $config['upload_path'] = './resources/images/events_photo/temp/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['file_name'] = uniqid().'.jpeg';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_error', $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
}
```

View

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('events/add_now'); ?>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Event_Name" value="<?php echo set_value('Event_Name'); ?>" placeholder="Enter Event Name">
                            <small class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('Event_Name'); ?></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Event_Start" value="<?php echo set_value('Event_Start'); ?>" placeholder="Enter Start Date" onclick="this.type='datetime-local'" onblur="this.type='text'" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
                                <small class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('Event_Start'); ?></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Event_End" value="<?php echo set_value('Event_End'); ?>" placeholder="Enter End Date" onclick="this.type='datetime-local'" onblur="this.type='text'" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
                                <small class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('Event_End'); ?></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Location</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Event_Location" value="<?php echo set_value('Event_Location'); ?>" placeholder="Enter Event Location">
                                <small class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('Event_Location'); ?></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <textarea placeholder="Event Description" name="Event_Description" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Image Attachment (Optional)</label>
                                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile" value="<?php echo set_value('userfile'); ?>" placeholder="Upload Image">
                                <?php if($this->session->flashdata('upload_error')): ?>
                                <small class="text-danger"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('upload_error'); ?></small>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer text-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: @u_mulder Where can i check the error logs?

Comment: are you getting the image uploaded in folder ?

Comment: @HabibRehman No, its not uploading. i really cant resolve it

Comment: May be its your ```path``` issue or folder permission issue. Also you need to return something from this function ```do_upload()```.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter upload fail no error logs no error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717111/codeigniter-upload-fail-no-error-logs-no-error-reporting)