# php codeigniter 3.1.2 file upload issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

My CodeIgniter version is 3.1.2.

`Autoload.php` -> nothing added to autoload. When trying to upload I am getting HTTP 500.

Can anybody suggest a solution?

```
public function UploadProfileimage() {
        try {
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('upload');

            $profileimagefolder = 'C:' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'xampp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'htdocs' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'jalpp';
            if (!is_dir($profileimagefolder)) {
                mkdir($profileimagefolder, 0777, TRUE);
            }
            $config['upload_path'] = $profileimagefolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = 100;
            $config['max_width'] = 1024;
            $config['max_height'] = 768;


            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('profileimage')) {
                printv($this->upload->display_errors());
            } else {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //printv($e);
            echo ($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

output:

[image]

Comment: This error is occurs because when you click for upload when execution of code comes in this function there is a syntax error or there is not properly closed bracket in this function so localhost gives 500 error.

Comment: With any error message, 500 Internal Server Error, you will first want to check any Apache and PHP error logs for your server. These logs can provide valuable context related to any code failures or other potential causes of a site failure.

Comment: i have fully check, syntax error on this code.: $this->upload->initialize($config); and $this->load->library('upload'); not working properly

Comment: you have to replace all libraries with 2.2.6 libraries..becoz there is issue in 3.1.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter upload fail no error logs no error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717111/codeigniter-upload-fail-no-error-logs-no-error-reporting)

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this by using by  2.2 CI version's Upload library and mime type in 3.1.2
now it is working fine.

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

This is typically an indication of a syntax error in your PHP somewhere.  Your PHP error log will have an entry pointing you to the file and line number of the error.

If I were to speculate on the cause, I would guess its your `printv()` function call.  `printv()` is not a native PHP function, so unless you have defined it somewhere else, that is likely the cause.

Comment: printv is my custom function to print on test mode.